# Problems installing OpenMediaVault on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, arm, fastcgi, monit

BTW, I am trying to install OpenMediaVault on a Raspberry Pi 1, however, whenever I try and install OpenMediaVault on a Raspberry Pi 1, I get problems with the monit package, the FastCGI Process Manager and the openmediavault package too. Here is what happens with the package monit:

```
monit.service - LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/monit; generated)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) Since Fri 2020-05-22 13:49:54 BST; 30min ago
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting LSB: service and resource monitoring daemon...
May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi monit[4940]: Starting daemon monitor: monitSegmentation fault
May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi monit[4940]:  failed!
May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monit.service: Control process exit, code=exited, 
status=1/FAILURE
May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: monit.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 13:49:54 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: service and resource monitoring 
daemon.
```

Here is what happens with the FastCGI Process Manager:

```
php7.3-fpm.service - The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/php7.3-fpm.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Resul: signal) since Fri 2020-05-22 14:33:21 BST; 6min ago
Docs: man:php-fpm7.3(8)
Main PID: 416 (code=killed, signal=ILL)

May 22 14:33:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager...
May 22 14:33:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: php7.3-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=killed, 
status=4/ILL
May 22 14:33:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: php7.3-fpm.service: Failed with result 'signal'.
May 22 14:33:15 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 7.3 FastCGI Process Manager.
```

And here is what happens with the package openmediavault:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of openmediavault:
openmediavault depends on monit; however
Package monit is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package openmediavault (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
```

Can anyone help with this problem?

**NOTE:**
The problem could be depending on the version of the ARM processor we're dealing with. For an extra tag, I would say I am also talking about openmediavault.